# Problem with adobe-reader

Tags: adobe-reader

I cannot open the preferences dialog in adobe-reader. I want to uninstall it and get rid of all the configurations. How can I do that? I installed from the binary that was provided in adobe's website. I looked for `UNINSTALL` file, but I could not find it. I also tried `apt-get remove adobe-reader`, but that did not help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the correct file should be

```
sudo apt-get remove adobereader-enu
```

otherwise use synaptic and search for adobe

[ref](http://www.wujiewen.com/faq/content/16/43/en/how-to-remove-or-uninstall-adobe-reader-from-ubuntu.html)

Comment: I did all that, but there is still an item "Adobe Reader 9" in the main menu, which does not run but just shows a dialog that says that it cannot find the program, and after reinstalling, I get two of those items. And when I run one of them, the same problem arises again.

Comment: I would run the the removal again. Before installing anything else. Open your /home folder and look for the .HIDDEN adobe folder ~/.adobe, once located, open it up and delete the Acrobat or Acrobat Reader folder. Then proceed to reinstall

Comment: Thanks. After following your instructions, the "zombie" item in the main menu is still there (ending up with two items when reinstalled), but now, the trouble dissolved.

Comment: the "zombie" can be removed -right click on "menu" edit menus - scroll to it on the right side and find the "zombie" and delete.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

Open the terminal

```
cd /opt/Adobe/Reader9/bin 
sudo ./UNINSTALL
```